# Jquery focusout event is not working for checkbox in chrome browser

Tags: jquery

I have a form which will ask the customer to answer the questions in textfield, radio button option and check box as well. I have a scenario that I need to capture the time taken by a customer to answer a question. ie. the time difference between the customer intime and outime of a field. I have used an AJAX call to update the time in server. The intime is captured using jquery focusin event. The outtime is captured using jquery focusout event.

The above methodology is working in firefox browser. However in chrome browser,im facing problem in focusout event. The event is not triggered for radio buttons & check boxes. If I go from one text field to other fields, jquery focusout event is triggered properly. But the same is not working for radio buttons and check box as well.

Can someone help me to sort this issue out? Else can u give some suggestion how to capture intime and outime of a field.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dKrjt/6/) for your reference. Try out this with chrome and firefox to see the difference.

```
$('input').focusout(function(){
        alert("out");

          });​
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try this...

```
//Target just a checkbox
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    alert('Blurred');
});

//Target just a radio button
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    alert('Blurred');
});

//Target both

$('input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    alert('Blurred');
});
```

See Example: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/4JKPe/)

Comment: Onchange event will not work for radio button to capture the intime and outime of a field. If there is two radio button, how do i differentiate the buttons. please see the fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/dKrjt/6/